# jQuery: Target attribute with special character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following div:

```
<div data-id=""> </div>
```

And I want to target it using jQuery. This doesn't work:

```
jQuery("[data-id='']").text('hello');
```

How can I target div with this special character?

Comment: The code work properly. See https://jsfiddle.net/ofb0hrLz/

Comment: Try to use jQuery ready `$(function() { /* your code */ });`

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in stacksnippet?

Comment: @jcubic *ready*... you son of a... works now. Of course!

Comment: The code works as Mohammad has said!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$("div[data-id='']").text('hello');
```

Or you can also do it like this

```
$("[data-id='']").text('hello');
```

This code is working for me you can see this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("[data-id='']").text('hello');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-id=""></div>
    <div data-id="2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is diffrence of your code and question code? You changed `JQuery` to `$`.

Comment: You may have some other issue